# Conditional criteria in ordered array in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

We're currently looking at moving from code-based validation to a JSON Schema driven validator.

A common scenario for us is to change our validation criteria in one array item, in an ordered array, depending on the value(s) of an array item that came before it. A generic example would be where array items represent columns or rows in spreadsheets.

Is this something that is possible using an existing system such as if-then? If So How?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what your constraint is, there are some things you can do with JSON Schema. You can't do relative indexing, such as: if an array item's value is "foo", then the item before/after it must be a number greater than 3. But you can express something like: if item at index 2 is "foo", then the item at index 3 must be a number greater than 3. You are limited, however, to static assertions, meaning you can't make an assertion about the value of a field in relation to another field. For example, you can express: item at index 2 is greater than item at in index 3.

Here's an example of the kind of assertion you can make. This expresses the example given in the previous paragraph: if item at index 2 is "foo", then the item at index 3 must be a number greater than 3.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",

  "type": "array",
  "prefixItems": [
    { "type": "boolean" },
    { "type": "string" },
    { "type": "string" },
    { "type": "number" }
  ],

  "if": {
    "type": "array",
    "prefixItems": [
      true,
      true,
      { "const": "foo" }
    ],
    "minItems": 3
  },
  "then": {
    "prefixItems": [
      true,
      true,
      true,
      { "exclusiveMinimum": 3 }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you are using a draft older than 2020-12, you can change `prefixItems` to `items` to get the same result. The general pattern is to express the general constraints of the schema at the top level, then the conditions below. We want the `if` to match on the third value and don't care about first two, so we can put `true` or `{}` stubs in those slots. Same concept applies to the `then`. This can result in a lot `true`s if you have a lot of items, but there's no way around it because there is no way to specify an index a schema applies to. The `minItems` is also important because otherwise the `if` will match if the third item isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

> A generic example would be where array items represent columns or rows in spreadsheets.

I would not expect a schema or type definition language to be able to handle this. I suggest, instead, considering dynamically generating a json schema based on the column information, then handling the rest of the json (with the generated schema) to the validator.